# HTML5 and Java server application deployment on AWS

Tags: java, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a Java restful server application which can be compiled as a JAR/WAR file and I have another front-end application built using knockoutjs and HTML5 which talks to the Restful Server side application.

I am trying to deploy both on to Amazon Linux AMI EC2 Instance. I was successfully able to deploy the JAR after setting up a glassfish server on the server. The server side application is running completely fine.

I am having problems in understanding how the HTML5 application needs to be deployed on the AWS server. So that both can be accessible from the same server.

It would be great if some best practices are also suggested.Appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to put your GlassFish application server behind an HTTP server like Apache HTTPd or nginx, and either of those servers could then also serve your static content -- your HTML and JS. Check out http://www.codefactorycr.com/glassfish-behind-apache.html